# How to change Facebook theme

Tags: facebook

Can anybody tell me how to change the theme of Facebook with any extension? 
In Facebook, there is no theme change option.

Answer (score 1):

Officially there is no options to change the Facebook theme. But you can use Google Chrome extension, which gives the option to change the Facebook theme. There are 36 backgrounds to choose.

You must need to install Google Chrome.

[Facebook themes](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/facebook-themes-facebook/phejagnmddcjhjblnacgmejghffmhjfp?hl=en)

[Facebook background theme](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/facebook-background-theme/gmkibhckdgfaffmndpbjpeohfmoleijb?hl=en)